# Upgrading SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have upgraded my SQL Server 2014 to 2016 but still I have 2014 edition 
I don't know why, should I uninstall the 2014 version and why I have SQL Server 2014 edition still available after its been upgraded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Server 2014 installation is still available, because in SQL Server Installation Center you didn't made an in-place upgrade (which usually isn't a good idea), but you installed a new stand-alone instance:

[image]

It is possible two installations (instances) of SQL Server to work on the same server, but if you do not need SQL Server 2014 anymore, you can uninstall it (if you want to).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andrey Nikolov but I upgrade it, using upgrade from a previous version of SQL Server Option, That's why I put this question